# HTML & CSS Positioning

Tags: html, css

I have coded the layout below, but when tested the 'Login or Signup' link is not positioning to the right side of the page. Any help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```html
<header>
   <h1>Heading</h1>
   <p>A clean, minimal, grid-based layout focusing attention on your work.</p
   <a href="/">Login or Signup</a>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
  font-family: 'open sans';
  color: #333;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

**Desired Outcome**

[image: http://oi38.tinypic.com/161nqrd.jpg]

Comment: It is coming to the right.

Comment: One reason could be because you're missing a '>' at the end of your paragraph. Two: have you created the `header` element using javascript?

Comment: @Vivek It's not. The image is edited to show the desired outcome.

Comment: @hrr I have tried that, but does not seem to be working.

Comment: add a{position:relative;} in css

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working solution:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alp82/L8HTx/)

html

```
<header>
   <a href="/">Login or Signup</a>
   <h1>Heading</h1>
   <p>A clean, minimal, grid-based layout focusing attention on your work.</p>
</header>
```

css

```
body {
  font-family: 'open sans';
  color: #333;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
}

header a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing, please write html in correct way and write css with class name.

here is your answer :

HTML :

```
<header>
   <h1>Heading</h1>
   <a href="#">Login or Signup</a>
  <p>A clean, minimal, grid-based layout focusing attention on your work</p>     
</header>
```

CSS :

```
* {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }

 body {
   font-family: 'open sans';
   color: #333;
  }

 header {
   padding: 20px;
  }

 a {
   color: #333;
   text-decoration: none;
   float: right;
  }

 h1, h2 {
   font-weight: 300;
   margin :0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 header h1{
   width: 70%;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 header a{
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
 }
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/erasad22/346mq7on/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a missing `>` at the end of `<p>...</p>`

Then try this :
CSS

```
a
{
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;   
display : block;
float : right;
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
<a href="/">Login or Signup</a>
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>A clean, minimal, grid-based layout focusing attention on your work.</p>
</header>
```

And the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HxWNh/

Answer (score 0):

Some small changes. the H1 and p have full width so a must be below p. Change the css to

```
    a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 70px;
}
p{width: 70%;float: left;}
h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
```

Will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="wrapper" style="margin:auto; width:960px:">
        <div class="header" style="height:80px;">
            <div style="float:left">
                <h1 style="float: left;">Heading</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="login" style="float:right">
                           <a href="/">Login or Signup</a>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="DisplayArea" style="float:left;">
           <p>A clean, minimal, grid-based layout focusing attention on your work.</p>
       </div>
   </div>
```

```
.wrapper{
     margin:auto;
     width:960px;
    }
```

See if this helps...

i always find it easy to easy n convenient to position elements using .