# HTML5 & CSS Layout

Tags: html, css

I have coded the layout below, but when tested the 'Login or Signup' link is not positioning to the right side of the page. Any help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```html
<header>
   <h1>Heading</h1>
   <p>A clean, minimal, grid-based layout focusing attention on your work.</p
   <a href="/">Login or Signup</a>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
  font-family: 'open sans';
  color: #333;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

**Desired Outcome**

[image: http://oi38.tinypic.com/161nqrd.jpg]

Comment: What have you tried?  HTML elements do not magically align themselves after reading your mind.  None of your CSS tells the signup button to be aligned anywhere but the default alignment.

Comment: Note, your <p> tag is not closed

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML & CSS Positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129499/html-css-positioning)

Answer (score 2):

Close the `<p>` tag

```
<header>
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>A clean, minimal, grid-based layout focusing attention on your work.</p>
<div id="login"><a href="/">Login or Signup</a><div>
</header>
```

Put a div over the link to float it right. Is one option.

```
#login{
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this layout by using floats, and wrapping different sides of the page in `div` tags, which essentially act as containers.

HTML:

```
<header>
<div id="title-desc">
   <h1>Heading</h1>
   <p>A clean, minimal, grid-based layout focusing attention on your work.</p>
</div>
<div id="login-box">
   <a href="/">Login or Signup</a>
</div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#title-desc{
float: left;
}

#login-box{
float: right;
}
```

## [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NcNat/2/)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<header>
   <a href="/">Login or Signup</a>
   <h1>Heading</h1>
   <p>A clean, minimal, grid-based layout focusing attention on your work.</p>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: 'open sans';
  color: #333;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
}

header a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjr5K/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would put your *login/signup* into it's own div or span or something. And then specify the position of where you want it in the CSS.